# How did Vanellope von Schweetz's name get identified in the contestant's board?

Tags: disney, wreck-it-ralph

In *Wreck-It-Ralph*, Vanellope takes the gold medal from Ralph and uses it to compete in the next day's race.

When King candy announces each participant's name, based on the gold coins thrown in the gold coin collector, how did Vanellope's name get on the board?

Since other contestants won their coins from their previous games, there is a chance of having their names in the coin. But Vanellope has only thrown a gold medal that does not even belong to her. How did the gold coin collector know it is Vanellope's?  She is a glitch and not even a usual competitor in race.  How come the board is able to find that the last contestant is Vanellope von Schweetz?

Comment: Well, there is no reason why game code cannot identify a medal with the one who threw it. Software doesn't have to work the same way real life works.

Answer (score 23):

Vanellope isn't "just a glitch".

> She's hardwired into the system not only as a contestant, but as a featured player since she's actually the Princess of Sugar Rush, and is only a "glitch" because King Candy altered the code of the game to hide her identity, and all memory that he wasn't the original leader.

The system that identifies participants in the races presumably draws from a database of participants.  Vanellope is in that database, even if her data was somewhat corrupted.

It is safe to assume that the normal gold coins aren't imprinted with the identity of the specific racer who won them, as that would require that the coins be updated after each race is completed.  It seems likely that the system merely keeps track of which racers drop a coin in the collector.  The fact that the one Vanellope drops in the collector is actually Ralph's medal from a completely different game, yet is still recognized by the system, supports this theory.

Comment: *Is* Vanellope in that database? When we see the "code", she has no connections to anything else. I think the she's lucky that the system apparently doesn't have garbage collection.

Comment: @ksmarts he probably didn't cascade the delete correctly...

Answer (score 2):

The medal was still a gold coin, and it had Vanellope's fingerprints on it, I'm sure. Plus, she wasn't always a glitch. It was revealed at the end

> that she had been sabotaged by Turbo and that she was actually the main racer in the game.

Answer (score -2):

1. The cup probably knew that it was Vanellope who threw the medal because she kissed it before she threw. It's tecnology they live in so the cup probably has sensors or something that scans her spit on it, aka DNA. So the cup knew it was her.
2. It is still a gold coin looking thing and she has probably tried before but didn't win, and that was before she was a glitch. So the cup recognized her DNA

Comment: If your first point holds true, then what about the gold coin of other players. Is it neccessary for them to kiss before throwing their coins? But anway this is a great assumption

Comment: The coins are in circulation—wouldn't each have DNA from multiple racers?